# MySQL pattern matching - finding the match

Tags: mysql, database, pattern-matching, data-analysis

I'm working with a MySQL database that contains a substantial amount of data (about 10.000 records). The data in the database is logging of a machine maintenance, one of the fields contains a basic timeline (just steps that are timestamped) explaining all the work done. In this field I'm looking for certain strings that can indicate certain procedures (i.e. ABC123.ABC, abc111.abc, abc001.abc).

I'm looking for matches in this field with pattern matching like such

```
SELECT * FROM [tablename]
WHERE `work_performed` LIKE '% ______.___ %'
ORDER BY id DESC;`
```

The regex is very general but I can specify that further myself.

However, since the field which contains the string I'm looking for can be very large (up to 2364763 characters) i want to return the records matching the pattern specified but I also want to return a field that contains just the matched expression so I can confirm it is actually what I'm looking for and can use that string further.

I have found people with the same issue but I cannot reproduce their results.
Something like this might work?:

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING(`work_performed`, 
patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', `work_performed`)-1, 5) as match
FROM [tablename]
WHERE `work_performed`LIKE '% ______.___ %'
```

I would like to get output that looks somewhat like this:

```
+----+-------------------------------------------+------------+
| id |              work_performed               |   match    |
+----+-------------------------------------------+------------+
|  1 | 2017-02-26|10:59| Arrival: admin1         | ABCD12.adb |
|    | 2017-02-26|10:59| diagnosed error ab-0001 |            |
|    | 2017-02-26|11:02| ran ABCD12.adb          |            |
|    | 2017-02-26|11:03| system back online      |            |
+----+-------------------------------------------+------------+
|  2 | 2017-02-26|10:59| Arrival: admin34        | abc123.ags |
|    | 2017-02-26|10:59| diagnosed error WP1234  |            |
|    | 2017-02-26|11:02| ran abc123.ags          |            |
|    | 2017-02-26|11:03| system back online      |            |
+----+-------------------------------------------+------------+
```

I apologise if I didn't give enough details but I'm an intern at a major company and we have very strict rules about confidentiality.

If there is a need for any additional information I will try to.

EDIT

I have been trying to search for the string I'm looking for with regexp, but I cant get it to work as I want to, here is what I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE `work_performed` regexp '% ([a-z]^3)([0-9]^3).([a-z]^3) %'
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: Do you want to _match_ the pattern, or you want to actually _extract_ matches as well?  Note that your expected output would be hard to generate using MySQL alone.  Most likely, you would generate that in your presentation layer.

Comment: I want to select all the rows that have a match in the specified field, but I want to display what triggered the match because the entries of the logbook are sometimes done by hand and I cannot really expect them to be 100% correct. Therefore I want to look at what the match itself was.

Comment: could be there only one dot `.` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That is correct. in the procedure name i'm looking for there can be only one dot

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `CONCAT`, `SUBSTR`, `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `LOCATE` functions:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(work_performed, '.', 1), ' ', - 1),
        '.',
        SUBSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(work_performed, '.', - 1), 1,
            LOCATE(' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(work_performed, '.', - 1))
        )
    ) m
FROM
    tablename
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

[***DEMO link***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cb78/1)

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer. this works perfect for the example but is unfortunately not specific enough, i get all sorts of records back that dont actually match the pattern i specified in my question (______.___). the thing that gets me the best percentage of correct matches is regex: '% ______.___ %'. but ofc i cant use that in a select. is there any way to specify the substr to better match that?